# PowerShell Script for SharePoint Add Item & Update Item gets stuck at $item.Update()

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I have ran into kind of strange issue today with my SharePoint 2013 Farm. I have one PowerShell Script(Runs in App Server) to Add Items to a List. Suddenly, this Script is taking very long time to go to next line after it calls `$item.Update()`.

But the same time If I run the same script on my Front End Server. It works as expected without any Delay.

Sample script below:

> ```
>     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
> $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity https//dddl/xxxxsecurityservice
> $List=$web.Lists["MIC GatePass-2"] 
> $List.ItemCount
> $item= $List.AddItem()
> $item["Title"]="Item1";
>  Get-Date
> write-host "Adding..."
>
> $item.Update(); #Gets stuck here but I can see the Item has been added.
>
> write-host "Done..."
> Get-Date
> ```

Could somebody give a hint or suggestion what is going on here?

**Note**: I have created Test List and used PowerShell to add new item from the server(App Server) where I have the issue, It worked fine.

Comment: Without seeing the full script, it’s hard to determine what could be the cause to the bad performance.

Comment: Thank you christoffer, 
  I have  updated the question.